# Graphics cover the text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

On https://english.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged, one of the blocks appears as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The graphic covers the block title.

Comment: I see this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Sorry for the delay in getting to this!